# How to translate this mySQL query to $wpdb query

Tags: mysql, wpdb

I'm having trouble recreating a query from straight mySQL to `$wpdb` compatible.

```
SELECT meta_value
FROM `wp_postmeta`
WHERE meta_key = 'review_rating'
AND meta_value = 5
AND post_id IN (118,117,116,115,114,113,112,110,109,161)
```

When testing in Sequel Pro app it returns the correct number of posts that match the meta_value from the post_ids but when used in Wordpress it only returns "1"

Not sure what I'm doing wrong on including an integer/number into the SQL query. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your code, or it is as if you haven't asked at all....

Comment: Why use custom SQL where you loose all filters and caches. Use `WP_Query` which will build a more reliable SQL query